# Lazy loading in magento2.3

Tags: magento2, lazyload

I want to implement lazy loading on my homepage.
Does anyone have any example for how to implement lazy loading?

Comment: what have you tried? what are you trying to lazy-load

Comment: i am trying to lazy load products on homepage

Comment: have you tried using the widgets?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement lazy loading with the help of a free extension by Weltpixel that I am using on my Magento 2 site. With this you could also have it implemented on other pages too. I hope this helps.